# Reading in a CSV file for integers

Tags: c++, filestream

I have a test file set up here trying to read in a CSV file

```
ifstream file;

    file.open("New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.csv");
    string temp;
    string arr[15];
    int size = 0;
    int index = 0;

    while (getline(file, temp, ','))
    {
        if (!temp.empty())
        {
            arr[index] = temp;
            std::cout << arr[index];
            size++;
            index++;
        }
    }
```

Output

```
34568
29774
18421
```

it successfully captures each index, and even lines them out in a row (I'm guessing its also capturing a \n?)

however I need them to be integers, I would do this in the same loop with a stoi() function, but I need the size of the array to be dynamic (I don't want to use vectors here because this is fitting into another part of code that needs an array)

Here is how I turn them into integers and put them in a new array

```
    int *intArr = new int[size];

        for (index = 0; index < size; index++)
        {
                intArr[index] = stoi(arr[index]);
                std::cout << intArr[index];

        }
```

and here is the output for this

```
3456897748421
```

It seems to miss each number after it switches to the next row in the csv
If I structure it properly, heres whats going on

```
34568
 9774 
 8421
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with CSV files giving a `\n` at the end of a row in an excel file. 
How do I fix this? I need all the values to be integers, thanks!

Comment: Can you show us some sample content of your CSV file?

Comment: Have you tried using `std::istringstream ss(thestring); ss >> thevalue;` instead of `std::stoi`?

Comment: @brc-dd my CSV file looks exactly like the first output, it matches each row as well

Comment: @brc-dd I'll also try doing that rn

Comment: Your code will not work for such csv file (file having no comma), because the delimiter `,` passed to `getline` is never encountered in the whole file. It is basically reading the whole file in a string. You can verify this by printing the value of `index` onto your console.

Comment: actual CSV parsing is never done like that. You should apply line by line approach, i.e. get a line (using `getline`, delimiter set to default, `\n`) and then tokenise it using `,` as tokeniser.

Comment: Sorry, I mean that I have an excel file with those numbers in them, and they are seperated by ',' since its a CSV file already, I can read the numbers in correctly as a string, but the ```getline``` is including a newline, I need to get rid of that newline, your stringstream idea works great for transfering into an integer but its still including a newline operator and removing a value from my table

Comment: Format of your CSV is not clear. Can you please open your CSV using notepad (not excel) and show us what you see there?

Comment: Figured it out! I needed two while loops, answer below

Comment: Also check out my code: https://wandbox.org/permlink/micv1wA9dPTeFe8B. It is advised to use `std::vector` in place of static array if you are not sure that you file always contain 15 entries.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, you need two while loops like this:

```
while (getline(file, temp))
    {
        istringstream ss(temp);

        while (getline(ss, data, ','))
        {
             arr[index] = data;

            std::cout << arr[index];
            size++;
            index++;
        }
    }
```

I'm not exactly sure why you need two, because this seems kind of redundant, but getting the line THEN putting it in a string stream seems to get rid of that new line

Thanks to @brc-dd for the help!